# SQL Query Speed

Tags: sql, performance, reporting

I'm building a report that collates a huge amount of data, the data for the report has taken shape as a view which runs in about 2 to 9 seconds (which is acceptable). I also have a function that returns a set of ids which needs to filter the view:

```
select *
from vw_report
where employee_id in (select id from dbo.fnc_security(@personRanAsID))
```

The security function on its own runs in less than a second. However when I combine the two as I have above the query takes over 15 minutes.

Both the view and the security function do quite a lot of work so originally I thought it might be down to locking, I've tried no lock on the security function but it made no difference.

Any tips or tricks as to where I may be going wrong?

It may be worth noting that when I copy the result of the function into the in part of the statement:

```
select *
from vw_report
where employee_id in (123, 456, 789)
```

The speed increases back to 2 to 9 seconds.

Comment: It is difficult to answer if we don't know what RDBMS you are using (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, PostGreSQL, SQLite…) and what version of that RDBMS. Their implementation of SQL differ and there are features that we could use to improve the query efficiency for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up dumping the result from the security function into a temporary table and using the temporary table in my main query. Proved to be the fastest method.

e.g.:

```
create table #tempTable (id bigint)

select id 
into #tempTable
from dbo.fnc_security(@personRanAsID)

select *
from vw_report
where id in (select id from #tempTable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, any extra background will help here...
- Do you have the code for the view and the function?
- Can you specify the schema and indexes used for the tables being referenced?

Without these, advise become difficult, but I'll have a stab...

1). You could change the IN clause to a Join.
2). You could specify WITH (NOEXPAND) on the view.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  vw_report WITH (NOEXPAND)
INNER JOIN
  (select id from dbo.fnc_security(@personRanAsID)) AS security
    ON security.id = vw_report.employee_id
```

Note: I'd try without NOEXPAND first.

The other option is that the combination of the indexes and the formulation of the view make it very hard for the optimiser to create a good execution plan.  With the extra info I asked for above, this *may* be improvable.

Comment: Note: The NOEXPAND part is MS SQL Server.  Other RDBMSs may have similar options.

Answer (score 0):

It takes so much time because sub-select query executing for each row from vw_report while the second query doesn't. You should use something like:

```
select *
from vw_report r, (select id from dbo.fnc_security(@personRanAsID)) v
where r.employee_id = v.id
```